# Yii CGridview indexed filters

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

i have custom fields for CGridView. Every column is different Custom Field with it's id. Displaying them is just fine. Problem begins when i try to apply filter for these fields.

I have 4 filter with names `CustomField[5]`, `CustomField[6]`, `CustomField[8]` and `CustomField[12]` indexed by it's id. After filtering, yii generates wrong query:

[image: Wrong query]

As you can see, it's making loop till last element (since largest id is 12, so it is looping till 12). But if i add letter (making index as string) it generates correct query:

[image: Correct query]

Filter dropdown is generated with code:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList(
    "CustomField[{$column->id}]",
    $this->getFilterValue($column),
    ['' => ''] + CustomFieldValue::getValue($column),
    $column->tagOptions
);
```

It generates this html:

```
 <tr class="filters">
    <td>
        <select id="CustomField_5" name="CustomField[5]">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="29">Olympic Male Fly -58</option>
            <option value="33">Olympic Female Bantam -57</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="CustomField_6" name="CustomField[6]">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="4">Quarter-finals</option
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="CustomField_8" name="CustomField[8]">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="3">Bronze</option>
            <option value="1">Gold</option>
            <option value="4">Participation</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="CustomField_12" name="CustomField[12]">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="2">Silver</option>
            <option value="1">Gold</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any idea what is wrong how to fix it?

Comment: Could you add the html generated for one of the filters without the letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

This is an issue with the way `jquery.ba-bbq.js`'s [`deparam` function](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/js/source/jquery.ba-bbq.js#L467) handles the url parameters. If the parameters are passed as a url string i.e `&a=b&c=d..`, it creates an object out of them. In the process it treats any parameters that are numerically indexed as arrays and pads them with empty elements.

Here's the result of `serialize` on your filter html:

```
CustomField[5]=&CustomField[6]=&CustomField[8]=&CustomField[12]=
```

And here's the result of `$.param.querystring` on the serialized string

```
CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&
CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&
CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=&CustomField[]=
```

```js
$(function(){
        $("#clickme").on("click", function(){
           var data = $(".filters select").serialize();
           $("#serialized").html(decodeURIComponent(data) + "\n\n" + decodeURIComponent($.param.querystring("", data)));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yiisoft/yii/master/framework/web/js/source/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
    <select id="CustomField_5" name="CustomField[5]">
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
      <option value="29">Olympic Male Fly -58</option>
      <option value="33">Olympic Female Bantam -57</option>
    </select>
    <select id="CustomField_6" name="CustomField[6]">
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
      <option value="4">Quarter-finals</option>
    </select>
    <select id="CustomField_8" name="CustomField[8]">
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
      <option value="3">Bronze</option>
      <option value="1">Gold</option>
      <option value="4">Participation</option>
    </select>
    <select id="CustomField_12" name="CustomField[12]">
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
      <option value="2">Silver</option>
      <option value="1">Gold</option>
    </select><br/>
    <button id ="clickme">Serialize</button>
  </div>  
  <pre><div id="serialized"></div></pre>
```

**The Solutions**

1. Prefixing your indexes with a string solves the problem since it results in the parameter `CustomField` being treated as an object not an array.
2. An alternative solution would be to ensure that your custom fields have continuous indexes i.e `0,1,2,3`.
3. Also, you could just ignore any empty `CustomField` parameters in your controller action.

Comment: First solution looks like waste of resources and time for parcing. Second one is not possible, since indexes must be the same as the ones in database. I will try third solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think yii considers `CustomField[{$column->id}]` as an array indexed. This also has to do with dropdown list formation in yii. So why don't you resolve it by making `name` the same as `id`:
CustomField_{$column->id}

Comment: Because i need it indexed. If i make name `CustomField_{$column->id}`, i will have to parse _POST additionally.

Comment: @Justinas, have you tried to force parser to consider CustomField's index as string: `CustomField['{$column->id}']` ?